# Rails - paperclip - Multiple photo upload not saving

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

I'm trying to make a create product page in rails. This includes adding multiple images and text fields. I have one model for products and one for photos. I'm using the paperclip gem for photo upload.
But I get no picture when I view product page. Photos are not being saved to database.

P.S. I use HAML.

**app/views/products/show.html.haml**

```
  %b Name
  = @product.name
  %br

  %b Description
  = @product.description

  %br
  - @product.photos.each do |photo|
  = image_tag photo.image.url
```

**app/controllers/products_controller**

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :require_login
    before_filter :current_user, only: [:create, :destory]

  def new 
    @product = Product.new
    @photo = Photo.new
    5.times { @product.photos.build }
  end

  def create

  @photo = current_user.photos.build(params[:photo])
  @product = current_user.products.build(params[:product])
    if @product.save
        render "show", :notice => "Sale created!"
    else
        render "new", :notice => "Somehting went wrong!"
    end
end

  def show
    @product = Product.find(params[:id]) 
  end
```

**app/models/photo**

```
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :product_id    
  belongs_to :product
  has_attached_file :image,
    :styles => {
      :thumb=> "100x100#",
      :small  => "300x300>",
      :large => "600x600>"
        }
end
```

**app/models/product**

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :description, :name, :price, :condition, :ship_method, :ship_price, :quantity, :photo
  has_many :photos, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :photos
  belongs_to :user
end
```

**user model**

```
   class User < ActiveRecord::Base
      attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :name

      attr_accessor :password
      has_many :products, dependent: :destroy
      has_many :photos,:through=>:products
```

**app/products/new.html.haml**

```
= form_for @product, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f|
  %p
    = fields_for :photos do |f_i|
      =f_i.file_field :image
```

Comment: remove this line **has_attached_file :photo** from your Product model there is no need of it here.

Comment: i don't understood so far why you are asking same question again... What about old one? you are wasting others time..
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16665809/ruby-on-rails-paperclip-not-saving-to-database

Comment: and third one is here 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16807112/rails-paperclip-is-not-adding-my-image

Answer (score 3):

First your form is wrong, q for registration of photos used fields_for, then you use fields_for f.object.photos or use Photo.new do | g |, the other in your relationship model is wrong has_attached_file is has_many photos, the has_attached_file Paperclip is proper to be used in the model to be used not in the relationship with the other model. Hope this helps, now to have a product with several photographs, I recommend you use the gem cocoon, I q goes according to your case, https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon

Comment: This is not articulate enough

Answer (score 3):

You had written under Photo model as:

```
has_many :photos, :through => :products
```

This doesn't make any sense..
in your Photo model write

```
belongs_to :product
```

while in Product model write:

```
has_many :photos
```

actually this will be one-to-many relation as far i had understood:

There is no need to write has_attached_file in product model. This will be written under photo model like

```
has_attached_file :image
```

Now you have multiple photos for product. So you need loop for showing those photos. e.g., in your show view do some thing

```
<% unless @product.photos.blank? %>
  <% @product.photos.each do |photo| %>
    <%= image_tag photo.image.url %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

__*_*__*_*_ EDIT 2 ***_*__*_*__*_*_**

in your Product model

```
has_many :photos, :dependent => :destroy
accepts_nested_attributes_for :photos, :allow_destroy => true
attr_accessible :photos_attributes
```

in your photo model

```
belongs_to :product
attr_accessible :product_id
```

in your products controller

```
def new 
  @product = Product.new
  5.times { @product.photos.build }
end

def create
  @product = Product.new(params[:product])
  @product.user_id = current_user.id
  if @product.save
      render "show", :notice => "Sale created!"
  else
      render "new", :notice => "Somehting went wrong!"
  end
end
```

in your new.html.haml

```
= form_for @product, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f|
  - if @product.errors.any?
    .error_messages
      %h2 Form is invalid
      %ul
        - for message in @product.errors.full_messages
          %li
            = message
  %p
    = f.fields_for :photos do |f_i|
      =f_i.file_field :image
```

try out now. !

Comment: huh ... thats weird they are not

Comment: any ideas on what i should do

Answer (score 1):

After looking at your code. Its quite straight forward that Product don't have any image attribute at all. Photo have image attribute.

So you have to access Products -> photos -> images

Do this in controller show action

```
@product = Product.find(id)
@photos = @product.photos
```

In show.html.erb

```
-@photos.each do |photo|
= image_tag photo.image.url
-end
```

For haml syntax my applogies as these days working on project using html.erb. SO correct haml syntax if there is any error.

Answer (score -1):

I think

```
5.times { @product.photos.build }
```

should be in #new method
cuz .build method interact with @fields_for

Comment: His relationship between models messed up.

Answer (score -1):

```
   @product.image requires image to be the attribute of product model means image fields should be in products table.

   @product.image should be @product.photo.image.url
```

Comment: Didn't work i end up getting undefined method `photos' for nil:NilClass

Comment: there are multiple photos for product..  @product.photo will not work, i guess need a loop for displaying all photos!